# What is a more succinct way of converting python boolean to javascript boolean literals?

Tags: python

I want to convert a python boolean into JS's boolean literal. This is what I am working with:

```
store = dict(vat=True)

if store['vat']:
    store.update({'vat': 'true'})
else:
    store.update({'vat': 'false'})
```

Is there a more less verbose way to replace this code snippet ?

Comment: The same, but shorter would be `store['vat'] = 'true' if store['vat'] else 'false'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> store['vat'] = json.dumps(store['vat'])
>>> store
{'vat': 'true'}
```

Answer (score 3):

In JS a positive integer value is effectively true, and 0 (zero) is false.

You may try passing 0 as a JS false, and 1 as a JS true (do not use negative values)

```
>1 == true
true
>0 == true
false
>0 == false
true
>1 == false
false
```

Comment: If you're using Jinja2, you can do this using:
`let jsBoolean = {{ my_python_boolean|int }};`
This assumes you set `my_python_boolean` to `True` or `False`.